# Why can I call the stream() method on objects of a class that don't have the stream()-method?

Tags: java, collections, syntax, java-stream

I'm a novice Java programmer at university. I discovered something today that broke one of my conceptions about how Java syntax works.

```
public class testClass {

ArrayList <String> persons = new ArrayList <String> ();

public void run(){
    Stream <String> personstream = persons.stream();
}}
```

The method `stream()` is not found in the `ArrayList` class, yet it might appear as if it's there. When I move my mouse over the `stream()`-method in Eclipse, it says it's part of Collections, but I don't find the `stream()` method anywhere in its online documentation.

Why does it work to call the `stream()` method if it's not part of the class I'm calling it from?

Comment: It's in `Collection`, not `Collections`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you check the right class and Java version? Java 8's `Collection` (not `Collections`) has a [`stream()` default method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--), [which is inherited by `ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#methods.inherited.from.class.java.util.Collection):

```
/**
 * Returns a sequential {@code Stream} with this collection as its source.
 *
 * <p>This method should be overridden when the {@link #spliterator()}
 * method cannot return a spliterator that is {@code IMMUTABLE},
 * {@code CONCURRENT}, or <em>late-binding</em>. (See {@link #spliterator()}
 * for details.)
 *
 * @implSpec
 * The default implementation creates a sequential {@code Stream} from the
 * collection's {@code Spliterator}.
 *
 * @return a sequential {@code Stream} over the elements in this collection
 * @since 1.8
 */
default Stream<E> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, both you and the rest of the answerers. I looked up the AbstractCollections class, Collections class and Collections interface, but I never got around to searching the interface in Java 1.8. It's confusing for me...

Comment: @Magnus: Don't worry. It will get less confusing after a while, with practice

Answer (score 3):

[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) implements the [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface. This interface has the method `stream()`

Answer (score 1):

The method [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) is a *default* method defines in the interface `java.util.Collection`. Look at the source of `java.util.Collection`.

It uses the method `splititerator()` on `java.util.ArrayList` for the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is valid Java 8 code:

```
List<String> persons = new ArrayList<>();
Stream<String> stream = persons.stream();
```

`List<T>.stream()` is available.